# SwiftUI extra space at top of list above section header. On testing device only

Tags: swiftui

I have been trying to figure out what is causing the space at the top of the screen in my production app, so I made this test app to see if it is a bug or not. The code works as intended on a simulator but when a testing device runs the code it adds extra space. The space goes away after you start scrolling, and does not comeback until the view reloads. I have tried restarting the device and other devices. I took out .navigationTitle and .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode and it did not fix the problem. So far my best guess is that there is some problem with changing the section header in .onAppear(). Changing it to .task() seems to be a workaround for now.

[image: screenshot]

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @State var item: Item
    
    @State private var headerText = "Header"
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("\(headerText)")) {
                Text("Text")
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("Red Text")
            }.listRowBackground(Color.red)
            
        // Change to .task instead
        }.onAppear { 
            headerText = "Change Header"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Edit: Here is the code for the list view, it is the default new project setup.

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item), label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                    })
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }
```

Comment: The space is where the navigation title would take place. If you do not set any, use navigation title style inline.

Comment: My guess is that you have multiple Navigation Views and/or stacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this behaviour was caused by `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())`.

Looks like it's a bug with `NavigationView` in SwiftUI 4 since it wasn't like this before.

If you are on iOS 16 use `NavigationStack` instead `NavigationView`. This fixed all my problems and I didn't even need to use the navigationViewStyle anymore.

NavigationView is deprecated in favor of NavigationStack.